# AutoDelete shortcut from menu

Tags: android, android-intent

I want the user to be able to see my application in the menu only until he configurates it after that i want to remove the shortcut also i would like to put a shortcut on the users desktop.I am pretty new to java

It's there a way I can acheive this ?

Comment: In what menu? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Calvin in the application drawer

Comment: Launcher is the correct term. :) If that's the case, I have no idea because every installed app should appears there. But as an alternative, you can implement such that IF (config file not found) then show setting page Else show your main activity.

Comment: It's actually an intent filter in the manifest file that determines whether or not to show an app in the app drawer (not launcher).  From what I've seen it's not possible to change this after installation without hiding the application itself.  I'd consider Calvin's suggestion if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way that you could have it appear in the app drawer but remove it later.

To create a shortcut on the home screen you can use the following method.

**PLEASE NOTE -** I believe The intent that is being broadcast here, and the permission that you must request in your manifest are not a part of the public APIs. This method will not work on every home screen implementation. This method will potentially stop working at any time (and may already not work on newer versions of android, I only tested on Nexus S, but it does seem to work on that device).

***You have been warned***

```
    public boolean setShortCut(Context context, String appName)
{
    System.out.println("in the shortcutapp on create method ");
    boolean flag =false ;
    int app_id=-1;
    PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> res =p.queryIntentActivities( i,0);
    System.out.println("the res size is: "+res.size());

    for(int k=0;k<res.size();k++)
    {
        System.out.println("the application name is: "+res.get(k).activityInfo.loadLabel(p));
        if(res.get(k).activityInfo.loadLabel(p).toString().equals(appName)){
            flag = true;
            app_id = k;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag){
        ActivityInfo ai = res.get(app_id).activityInfo;

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
        shortcutIntent.setClassName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "SIZETESTDYNAMIC");

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));
        //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        System.out.println("in the shortcutapp on create method completed");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("appllicaton not found");
    return true;
}
```

and you'll have to add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```